# interpret everything after LeftBracket as a string until next RightBracket

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr4

[Solution]
on the bottom under Edit3

I am currently developring a new grammar (from certain requirements which I cannot change) and the following requirement poses a problem, I cannot solve at the moment. I am using Antlr4 with the C# target.

The syntax is as follows:

```
print [blabla ]
```

so everything inside the brackets is considered a string. So also this:

```
print [3 + 2]
```

will print

```
3 + 2
```

Now I have lexer rules which will obviously match the 3 as an Integer. So how can I create a parser rule which will parse anything until a ']' is found? I currently have the following production:

```
control
: 
| Print expr
| Print LeftBracket printArg RightBracket
    ;
```

the problem I am facing is that the left bracket does not always start a string. Sometimes (eg in while) the condition is also in brackets. I thought about just accepting every Lexer rule until the RightBracket is reached and then generate the string at runtime when I use the generated parse tree, but seems to me very annoying and I would need to insert the whitespaces later on which will be difficult.

If you need more parts of my grammar just ask in a comment and I will provide you with more details
Kind regards

Lukas

EDIT: more information about my grammar:
The following production use brackets:

```
Print LeftBracket printArg RightBracket
Repeat IntegerConstant LeftBracket body RightBracket
While LeftBracket expr RightBracket LeftBracket body RightBracket
If expr LeftBracket body RightBracket LeftBracket body RightBracket
SetPos LeftBracket IntegerConstant IntegerConstant RightBracket
```

EDIT2:
So I tried to use the modes but I got problems on returning from them. These are the code lines I have regarding the modes:

```
mode printMode;
WhitespacePrint
    :   [ \t]+
        -> skip
    ;
LeftBracketPrint : '[' -> popMode, pushMode(stringMode);
NotLeftBracket : ~'[' -> popMode;

mode stringMode;
String : ~']'+;
RightBracketPrint: ']' -> popMode;
```

And I added a pushMode(printMode) on the Print lexer rule (matches the keyword)
Now parsing print [ 1 + 2] creates a single token containing the whole string inside the brackets. Now when I use print 1 + 2 (which should output 3), I get a no viable alternative ar input 'print1' exception, since the '1' has a type of NotLeftBracket. How can I switch the mode without consuming the input?

EDIT3:
Next I tried to use some inline code and use lookahead which finally solved my problem:

```
mode printMode;
LeftBracketPrint : [ \t]+ '[' -> popMode, pushMode(stringMode);
WhitespacePrint
    :   [ \t]+ {_input.La(1) != '['}?
        -> skip, popMode
    ;

mode stringMode;
String : ~']'+;
RightBracketPrint: ']' -> popMode;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by treating everything inside brackets as a `BracketLiteral` in the lexer.

```
LeftBracket : '[' -> pushMode(BracketLiteralMode);

mode BracketLiteralMode;

  BracketLiteral : ~']'+;
  RightBracket : ']' -> popMode;
```

Before determining how the special cases would be handled, I would then enumerate every last possibility for where an exception to the `BracketLiteral` rule could appear in the grammar. If you can add those details, I would be able to make some suggestions regarding how to handle those cases.

Comment: added more information about my grammar. I appreciate your incredible help!

Comment: I was thinking if this would work: when I see a print, I would go into a printmode where everything except a '[' (and of corse whitespaces= would leave this mode and when I hit the '[' I would use your code to parse everything as a string. Would this be the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly there is duality in interpreting bracketed content, it is either string or expression depending on the context (for print it is a string).

2 possible scenarious:

- at lexer level check the context when hitting left bracket, and then either go into string mode, or regular mode (i.e. expression)
- also at lexer level create a buffer whenever you hit left bracket and fill it with following text, use the right bracket value (normally it is useless) as the vehicle to pass verbatim string

I think the first approach is easier, because in second you have to write parsing rules for the content of print, and this could be not parsable:

```
print [ a ++++ 2 ]
```